# How can I search between the lines with multiline search?

Tags: org-babel, search, icicles, helm-grep

I use `C-u 4 M-x helm-swoop` for interactive search also show several surrounding lines (this is analogous to `grep -C 4`).

When I find the word I narrow my search interactively, for example, 
`C-u 4 M-x helm-swoop` `foo bar`
And this is analogous to `grep -C 4 foo files | grep bar`.

I want to narrow my search more and search only code between the lines `#+BEGIN_SRC python` and `#+END_SRC`.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python
    search this code with "grep -c"
#+END_SRC
```

How can I do it with `helm-swoop` or `helm-occur`? Is there another solution?

Answer (score 2):

You apparently want to search only within certain **contexts**, defined by those two Org labels, `#+BEGIN_SRC python` and `#+END_SRC`.

You can use [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) to do that, defining the search contexts as text that matches a regexp, which you can input at the prompt:

```
#[+]BEGIN_SRC python\(.\|[\n]\)+#[+]END_SRC
```

But as a shortcut (and easier on the eyes) you can use the toggle key [`C-M-.`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Dot%2c_Dot%2c_Dot) to make typing just `.` have the effect of typing `\(.\|[\n]\)` (to match any char, including a newline), so just:

```
#[+]BEGIN_SRC python.+#[+]END_SRC
```

Then type `0` (accept the default), to match the whole regexp, (subgroup 0).

That searches all text from your start to your finish text.  If you don't want to include the delimiters then you can use this instead, and enter `1` for the subgroup:

```
#[+]BEGIN_SRC python\(.+\)#[+]END_SRC
```

Then, to search within the contexts, just type whatever pattern (e.g. a regexp) you want to match into the minibuffer and hit `S-TAB` to see the matches as completions in buffer `*Completions*`.  The matches update as you change the pattern in the minibuffer.  You can navigate among contexts by cycling (e.g. `C-<down>`).  You can narrow the candidates further with `S-SPC` and another search pattern. Etc.

---

But that context-defining regexp is far too simple. As you noted in a comment, it matches the text between the *first* `#+BEGIN_SRC` and the *last* `#+END_SRC`, producing only one context, which is useless.

Defining the contexts you really want is trickier.  For that, I looked in the Org code for a suitable regexp and found `org-babel-src-block-regexp`, which matches the text of *any* source block (not just `python`), including matching the delimiters `#+begin_src` and `#+end_src`.

Here's the value of `org-babel-src-block-regexp`:

```el
"^\\([  ]*\\)#\\+begin_src[     ]+\\([^ \f  \n
]+\\)[
]*\\([^\":\n]*\"[^\"\n*]*\"[^\":\n]*\\|[^\":\n]*\\)\\([^\n]*\\)\n\\([^\0]*?\n\\)??[
]*#\\+end_src"
```

That's the string form.  To use `icicle-search` *interactively* you would need to enter this at the prompt to define the regexp, and then enter `3` as the subgroup of the regexp to use as the context:

```el
^\([    ]*\)#[+]BEGIN_SRC[  ]+\([^  

]+\)[
]*\(\([^\":
]*\"[^\"
*]*\"[^\":
]*\|[^\":
]*\)\([^
]*\)
\([^\0]*?
\)??\)[
]*#[+]END_SRC
```

That's `org-babel-src-block-regexp`, but:

- With an extra `\(`...`\)` added around the part between the two delimiters.
- As a value that you would input in the minibuffer as a regexp. E.g., for `\n` you would use `C-q C-j` (which inserts a newline char).

Clearly you wouldn't want to be entering a regexp like that interactively!
Fortunately, you can also use function `icicle-search` to define your own search command.

Here's an Icicles-search command that incorporates `org-babel-src-block-regexp`, but with an extra `\\(`...`\\)` added around the part between the two delimiters:

```el
(defvar org-python-section-regexp "^\\([    ]*\\)#\\+BEGIN_SRC[     ]+python[
]*\\(\\([^\":\n]*\"[^\"\n*]*\"[^\":\n]*\\|[^\":\n]*\\)\\([^\n]*\\)\n\\([^\0]*?\n\\)??\\)[
]*#\\+END_SRC"
  "Regexp to match the content of Org-bable Python source sections.")

(defun icy-search-org-python-sections (beg end)
  "`icicle-search' with Org-babel python sections as contexts.
Type a regexp to match within each context."
  (interactive `(,@(icicle-region-or-buffer-limits)))
  (let ((icicle-search-context-level  2)
        (icicle-transform-function    (and (not (interactive-p))
                                           icicle-transform-function)))
    (unwind-protect
        (progn (face-remap-set-base 'icicle-search-main-regexp-others nil)
               (icicle-search beg end org-python-section-regexp t))
      (when icicle-search-cleanup-flag (icicle-search-highlight-cleanup))
      (face-remap-reset-base 'icicle-search-main-regexp-others))))
```

This is the part of that regexp that matches the text between the delimiters:

```el
\\(\\([^\":\n]*\"[^\"\n*]*\"[^\":\n]*\\|[^\":\n]*\\)\\([^\n]*\\)\n\\([^\0]*?\n\\)??\\)
```

That's thanks to the Org code -- glad I didn't have to come up with it!

All I did was take the value of `org-babel-src-block-regexp`
and substitute `python` for the more general pattern `\\([^ \f  \n
]+\\)`, and then wrap the between-delimiters part in `\\(` ... `\\)` so I could tell Icicles search to pick up all of that stuff.

Then I bound `icicle-search-context-level` to `2`, which is the regexp subgroup number to use for the context.

---

(See also the Isearch answer below. There are advantages to each: Icicles search and Isearch.)

Comment: With ```M-x icicles-search``` highlighted all text beetween first ```'#[+]BEGIN_SRC'``` and last ```'#[+]END_SRC'```, then ```Moving to sole context``` and ```Removing search highlighting...done```. That's all.

Comment: Right; thx. Updated to take care of that. Hope the explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses **Isearch**, not [Icicles search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview).  To make use of it you need library [`isearch-prop.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus): Search zones of text that have certain text properties (or overlays that have certain overlay properties).

First, here's a regexp that identifies the content of the Org-babel sections you cite. (This is the same `defvar` as in the Icicles answer here - see that answer for more about the regexp.)

```el
(defvar org-python-section-regexp "^\\([    ]*\\)#\\+BEGIN_SRC[     ]+python[
]*\\(\\([^\":\n]*\"[^\"\n*]*\"[^\":\n]*\\|[^\":\n]*\\)\\([^\n]*\\)\n\\([^\0]*?\n\\)??\\)[
]*#\\+END_SRC"
  "Regexp to match the content of Org-bable Python source sections.")
```

This command isearches forward in the contexts you want.  If you want *regexp* isearch forward then substitute function `isearchp-regexp-context-regexp-search` for `isearchp-regexp-context-search` in this code.

```el
(defun isearch-org-python-sections (&optional beg end)
  "Isearch within org-babel python sections, as contexts.
If ‘isearchp-complement-domain-p’ is non-nil then search *outside* the
contexts defined by the regexp.  (Use ‘M-= ~’ during Isearch to toggle
this variable.  Search is limited to the region if it is active."
  (interactive
   (let ((beg  (if (and transient-mark-mode  mark-active) (region-beginning) (point-min)))
         (end  (if (and transient-mark-mode  mark-active) (region-end) (point-max))))
     (list beg end)))
  (let ((isearchp-context-level  2))
    (isearchp-regexp-context-search nil beg end nil org-python-section-regexp)))
```

While searching, the area outside the zones is dimmed slightly, by default. This is from option `isearchp-dim-outside-search-area-flag`. (You can toggle this dimming during Isearch using `C-M-D` (aka `C-M-S-d`.)

Answer (score 0):

The newest master of [Elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep/blob/master/elgrep.el) provides searching of context.

It is available on Melpa. You can install it by <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install` <kbd>RET</kbd> `elgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> if [melpa](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) is in your `package-archives`.

The command `elgrep-menu`, bound to the new menu item `Tools -> Search Files (Elgrep)...`, provides you with the Elgrep menu where you can specify your search.

The items "**Context Lines Before The Match**" and "**Context Lines After The Match**" are bold. If you click on them you can choose between "*Number of Lines*" and "*Regexp*" for the context.

Input the regexp

```
^[[:space:]]*#\+BEGIN_SRC python
```

for the **context lines before** the match and the regexp

```
^[[:space:]]*#\+END_SRC
```

for the **context lines after** the match.

Clearly, you should also specify the regexp you want to search for within the specified context as "Regular Expression" in the Elgrep menu.